# How can I hold apscheduler from exiting the application

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a scheduler job that sends a post-request API. After adding the job to the scheduler, my script simply exits and I have no way of waiting to get the return result back.

```
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone=utc)
    scheduler.add_job(send_post_request, trigger="interval", minutes= interval, args=args)
    scheduler.add_listener(listener, EVENT_JOB_ERROR|EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED)
    scheduler.start()

    def listener(event: SchedulerEvent):
       """Listen to events"""

       print("Event listener...")
       print(event.retval)
```

I tried to add `listener` as well to get the return result but I don't know how to hold the script from exiting. I have seen people using `while True` but it ends up running infinitely. Apparently, I need to define when I want the script to stop running. I am thinking of defining global variable as a return result and using that to check for exiting conditions in `while True` but I can't get it right. I think it is not a good approach anyway so I am looking for better suggestions here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're only running the scheduler in the script, then you shouldn't be using `BackgroundScheduler`, but `BlockingScheduler`, as per the [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html#choosing-the-right-scheduler-job-store-s-executor-s-and-trigger-s). Just make sure you do all the scheduler initialization before you start the scheduler, because then the `start()` call will block until the scheduler is stopped.